# Install PHP 7.2 Support Patches for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.4

How to Install PHP 7.2 Support Patches for Magento 1 ?

What are the potential steps to install it on `Magento ver. 1.14.2.4` ?

Thankyou

Comment: you have download patch ?

Comment: No i want to download, but i am not sure where i can find the patch, I want to install patch for PHP 7.0 to 7.1 and 7.2

Comment: @RakeshDonga  Can you please advise how can install patch for PHP 7.0 to 7.1 and 7.2 on Magento ver. 1.14.2.4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get here patch :

[My Account](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/customer/account/login/) > Downloads Tab > Magento Commerce 1.X > Magento Commerce 1.x > Support and Security Patches > Security Patches > Security

after you install below way ...

https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/

here inchoo guideline available

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i can not see downloads tab

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal in your enterprise account ?

Comment: oh actually i was looking into another magento account. i think it should be their in enterprise account.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, one more question is their magento 7.1 patch available ? i can see 7.2 everywhere but in order to move from 7.0 to 7.2, i prefer to move first 7.0 to 7.1 patch then 7.2 patch.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal i have no more idea about that need to check in your account , because after july 31 magento1 support not available so need to write instruction for that

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the question.